# How to display count(*) of data that doesn't exist in my table im mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query

```
select count(1), is_purchased
from game_engine.temp 
group by is_purchased;
```

the result is shown below

```
count(1), is_purchased

1022, 1
```

it only shows the is_purchased that exist in the table I want to display it also if it doesn't exist to show as the below

```
count(1), is_purchased

1022, is Purchased
0, not Purchased
```

Comment: Column is_purchased data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest method is `union all`:

```
select count(1), 1 as is_purchased
from game_engine.temp 
where is_purchased = 1
union all
select count(1), 0 as is_purchased
from game_engine.temp 
where is_purchased = 0;
```

An alternative is to use a `left join`:

```
select is_purchased, count(t.is_purchased)
from (select 0 as is_purchased union all select 1 as is_purchased
     ) x left join
     game_engine.temp t
     using (is_purchased)
group by is_purchased;
```